# Setting Up Remote Linux Server For SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

**Background:**
I bought a computer and have Linux Ubuntu server 18.04.3 LTS installed on it. I can currently ssh into it via its internal ip address 192.168.1.26. I have private/public key enabled to login.

**Intentions:**
I would like to be able to access this server from college when I'm not home. I need help with the port forwarding and what I need to be doing to get access outside of the local network. But if there is no way of doing this securely I will just deal with not being able to access the server remotely.

If someone could help me out with linking an article or a video that explains this I would greatly appreciate the help! I'm new to Linux and networking so I apologize in advance.

Comment: Search the web for "port forwarding". You need to configure your router to forward TCP port 22 (ssh) to the Ubuntu computer. You may also need to assign a static IP to that machine. It may not always be 192.168.1.26. Finally, you probably want a domain name and dynamic DNS so you can find your home's public IP after it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a static public IP address at home you will need to set up a DynDNS on your router.

### Configure DynDNS

You can find some free domain name provider that allow to set up DynDNS for free like https://www.noip.com/

Then you will need to configure your router, do some researchs about your router and you will be able to do that. https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/how-to-configure-ddns-in-router/

Once you did this, your new domain name will always redirect to your home router even if your public ip address changes.

### Port forwarding

Next step is to forward incoming ssh requests to your Ubuntu server. Again you will find some information specific to your router by doing some researchs.

An example : https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/

I recommend you to use a free domain name like noip to do your tests and once you succeed buy a new domain name.